# datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, controls

I am able to bind the result of query to datagridview.
i.e., SELECT * FROM employee where empid=@empid to datagridview in winform.

What I need is a code that helps to update the result of this query on the datagridview & cause it to be showed on employee table in my database using c#.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What you really need is to read a few tutorials on the subject... Try googling for something like "DataGridView update C#".

Here are two I found:

[SwitchOntheCode.com](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database)
[csharp-online.net](http://en.csharp-online.net/Working_with_Data%E2%80%94Using_the_DataGridView)